# How to tune a frequency like 89.0 on Jusada ICS CM7 stock radio?

Tags: cyanogenmod, fm-radio

I am using Jusada Ice Cream Sunday ROM. I have problem with its stock radio app.

I can not tune to even numbers after decimal like 89.0 or 106.2. After the decimal it only let me tune to odd numbers.

How can I fix this? The above mentioned frequencies are popular radio stations in my region.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the app's settings try changing the default locale.  Different ones (even "China") will change the interval by which the tuner seeks.